# Drop rows of selected rows with null values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop rows with null values in both column a and b.
I have managed to find those rows with:

```
df[(df['a'].isnull()) & (df['b'].isnull())]
```

How do I drop these rows?

Comment: You just invert the mask: `df[~((df['a'].isnull()) & (df['b'].isnull()))]` I'm sure this has been answered before, looking for dupe

Comment: I didn't manage to find dupe. Thanks!

Comment: df.dropna(subset=['a','b'], how='all') really does what I want. And I think its a better approach. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert mask by `~`:

```
df[~(df['a'].isnull() & df['b'].isnull())]
```

Or:

```
df[df[['a','b']].notnull().any(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael ! 
df.dropna(subset=['a','b'], how='all') does what I want too !